# Output Event Emitter triggers only on ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript

I have parent and child component, from child need to trigger the parent component function.

**Parent.component.ts**

```
loadData(event) {
      console.log(event);
}
```

**Parent.component.html**

```
<app-project (uploaded)="loadData($event)" ></app-project>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Output() uploaded:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit() {
    this.uploaded.emit('complete'); // Worked 
}

loadProject(){
    this.uploaded.emit('complete'); // Not triggering the parent function 
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<button type="button" (click)="loadProject(project)" label="Load Project"></button>
```

Don't know what is the wrong in this, but workes from ngOnInit.

Calling the loadProject from child.component.html.

Comment: Where is `loadProject()` being called from?

Comment: There is a function (editProject) in child.component.ts from there calling 

editProject(project: Project) {
  this.uploaded.emit('complete');
}

Comment: Perhaps editing your question is a better idea because code in comments is hard to read. Please also add the information where `editProject()` is called from.

Comment: I'm sure `someMethod($event)` will be called in both cases. How does `someMethod() { ... }` look like?

Comment: So what's the problem or question then?

Comment: Loadproject() function will trigger while clicking the button from the child.component.html but the loadData function (emitter ) parent component function not triggering from Loadproject() function.

Answer (score 2):

change:

**child.component.ts**

```
@Output() uploaded = new EventEmitter<string>();

ngOnInit() {
    this.uploaded.emit('complete'); // Worked 
}

loadProject(){
    this.uploaded.emit('complete'); // Not triggering the parent function 
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<button type="button" (click)="loadProject()" label="Load Project"></button>
```

You were passing a string value to loadProject, but in child component there is no definition of loadproject that takes 1 parameter